eCatcher error: VPN tunnel error: TAP-Windows adapter 'Talk2m-eCatcher' not found
I've just started an eCatcher session.
When trying to connect to one of the Ewons, I get the following error message:

VPN tunnel error: TAP-Windows adapter 'Talk2m-eCatcher' not found
Retrying connecting Talk2M in ... seconds

I had a look at my device manager (network adapters), this is what I found (partially):

Edit: look deeper in "device stack" (list of devices?):
I had a deeper look at one of them (the "TAP-Windows Adapter V9" one), when asking for the Device stack, I saw following entries:

\Driver\FortiEDRBaseDriver...
\Driver\tap0901
\Driver\PnpManager

Where and how should I find this "Talk2m-eCatcher" TAP-Windows adapter?
Can anybody confirm that I need to see that "Talk2m-eCatcher" in my list of network connections? (I don't see it there):

In case yes, what do I need to do in order to add that "Talk2m-eCatcher" in that list?
Thanks in advance
Edit: result of "netsh dump"
netsh dump
#========================
# Interface configuration
#========================
pushd interface

popd
# End of interface configuration

# ----------------------------------
# 6to4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface 6to4

reset

popd
# End of 6to4 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# IPHTTPS Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface httpstunnel

reset

popd
# End of IPHTTPS configuration

# ----------------------------------
# IPv4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv4

reset
set global icmpredirects=enabled taskoffload=enabled
set interface interface="Ethernet (Kernel Debugger)" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Wi-Fi" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection* 1" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection* 2" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 2" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 6" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="VMware Network Adapter VMnet1" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="VMware Network Adapter VMnet8" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 5" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection 2" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection 3" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 3" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 4" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set subinterface interface= subinterface=ethernet_32757 mtu=65536
add address name="VMware Network Adapter VMnet1" address=192.168.13.1 mask=255.255.255.0
add address name="VMware Network Adapter VMnet8" address=192.168.32.1 mask=255.255.255.0

popd
# End of IPv4 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# IPv6 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface ipv6

reset
set interface interface="Ethernet (Kernel Debugger)" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Wi-Fi" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection* 1" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection* 2" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 2" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 6" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="VMware Network Adapter VMnet1" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="VMware Network Adapter VMnet8" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 5" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection 2" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Local Area Connection 3" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 3" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set interface interface="Ethernet 4" forwarding=enabled advertise=enabled nud=enabled ignoredefaultroutes=disabled
set subinterface interface= subinterface=ethernet_32757 mtu=65536

popd
# End of IPv6 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# ISATAP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface isatap

popd
# End of ISATAP configuration

# ----------------------------------
# 6to4 Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface 6to4

reset

popd
# End of 6to4 configuration

# ----------------------------------
# ISATAP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface isatap

popd
# End of ISATAP configuration

#========================
# Port Proxy configuration
#========================
pushd interface portproxy

reset

popd

# End of Port Proxy configuration

# ----------------------------------
# TCP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface tcp

reset

set global rss=enabled autotuninglevel=normal congestionprovider=default ecncapability=disabled timestamps=disabled initialrto=1000 rsc=enabled nonsackrttresiliency=disabled maxsynretransmissions=4 fastopen=enabled fastopenfallback=enabled hystart=enabled prr=enabled pacingprofile=off

popd
# End of TCP configuration

# ----------------------------------
# Teredo Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface teredo
set state type=disabled servername=win1910.ipv6.microsoft.com. servervirtualip=0.0.0.0

popd
# End of Teredo configuration

# ----------------------------------
# UDP Configuration
# ----------------------------------
pushd interface udp

reset

set global uro=disabled

popd
# End of UDP configuration

# ------------------------------------
# Bridge configuration (not supported)
# ------------------------------------

# ------------------------------------
# End of Bridge configuration
# ------------------------------------

The 'netsh advfirewall dump' command is not implemented in this version
of Windows. Instead, use the 'netsh advfirewall export' command to write
the current Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security configuration from
the current policy store to a file on disk. You can then use 'netsh
advfirewall import' to read the file and load it into another policy
store, such as a Group Policy object or the current policy store on
another computer. To set the current policy store, use the 'netsh
advfirewall set store' command.
For more information about the commands in the netsh advfirewall context,
see Netsh Commands for Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=111217.
# ----------------------------------------
# Wired LAN Configuration
# ----------------------------------------
pushd lan

popd

# End of Wired LAN Configuration.

Mobile Broadband configuration dump is not supported

# -----------------------------------------
# Remote Access Configuration
# -----------------------------------------
pushd ras

popd

# End of Remote Access configuration.

# -----------------------------------------
# Remote Access Diagnostics Configuration
# -----------------------------------------
pushd ras diagnostics

set rastracing component = * state = disabled

set modemtracing state = disabled

set cmtracing state = disabled

set securityeventlog state = disabled

popd

# End of Remote Access Diagnostics Configuration.

# -----------------------------------------
# Remote Access AAAA Configuration
# -----------------------------------------
pushd ras aaaa

popd

# End of Remote Access AAAA configuration.

# -----------------------------------------
# WinHTTP Proxy Configuration
# -----------------------------------------
pushd winhttp

reset proxy

popd

# End of WinHTTP Proxy Configuration

# ----------------------------------------
# Wireless LAN configuration
# ----------------------------------------
pushd wlan

# Allow filter list
# ----------------------------------------

# Block filter list
# ----------------------------------------

popd
# End of Wireless LAN Configuration


Meanwhile, my problem has been solved.
Apparently, there's a conflict between the installation of eCatcher and the installation of another tool (in my case SinemaRC Client): when SinemaRC Client gets installed after the installation of eCatcher, the eCatcher application's installation gets corrupted and unusable.
As a solution, I've uninstalled and re-installed eCatcher.
